# Why is 伴 used for buddy?

Tags: characters, etymology, radicals, glyph-origin

Is it true that 伴 comes from the word, 半(half) and thus can be interpreted as (significant other person)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

伴  is a [形聲字](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%BD%A2%E5%A3%B0%E5%AD%97) (Semantic-phonetic compound character)

The 亻 radical means 人 (person/ people) ; it is the semantic component of the character '伴' ( the word 'companion' is related to 'people')

半(bàn) is the phonetic component of the character 伴(bàn)

> *Is it true that 伴 comes from the word, 半(half) and thus can be interpreted as (significant other person)?*

No, you can have many companions, and a servant accompanies you is not your significant other